# Format structure tables in C using emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is there a library that would format structure tables?

something like:

```
struct a {
char *s;
int c;
int b;
} sample[] = {
{"this is a test", 1, 4},
{"this",3,56544}
};

So the reformatting would be :
} sample[] = {
{"this is a test", 1, 4},
{"this"          , 3, 56544}
};
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're looking for. Do you simply want to align things vertically on `,` in a given region?

Comment: Exactly, just alignment based on ','

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a region that includes all the values in your `sample[]` array, and then `C-u M-x align` that region.